# a Specialized string which can be used to recognize the blank values (Null Fields) that comes from the user interface

Tags: php, string, user-interface

I need a Specialized and Safe string which can be used to recognize the empty values  (blank Fields) that resulted when the user delete (erase) the content of the Input form in the user interface, in other words when the user wants to make the value of that field in the DB empty or null.

Note: I can't use Null because the code framework is using the Null value to recognize unedited fields In the UI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Used a random string and I send it as a value for each field that's has been emptied by the end user..
the customized framework is checking if the field value is equal to that random string and make the field value equals to null in database.